# USB headset audio stops when headset mic is on

Tags: windows, usb, audio, microphone, headset

I am not sure how this happened but before I was able to simultaneously use the microphone and listen to audio on the same headset.  Now whenever the microphone is on either via Discord or even the Windows audio settings window, the audio stops coming through even though I can see the VU(?) meter still bopping up and down to the music for the headset audio.  The audio does not return until the settings window is closed or voice chat is stopped.

It is a weird problem that I cannot find a solution for, I have reinstalled the drivers, updated whatever can be but to no avail.

I would appreciate any input with is problem bar a complete reinstall.  For the record this is a USB headset, a Sennheiser GSP350.  Thanks in advance!

[Image of Audio control panel clicking on the recording tab stops audio][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X36K.png)